# Join table with null in all group

Tags: sql, oracle

im new in stack. I cant found problem like this.

I have two tables.

One table x with transactions

```
Hour (approximation to full hour)   id_seler     expenses 
1:00                                    1             3,04
2:00                                    2             4,04
3:00                                    3             5,03
4:00                                    4             6,04
3:00                                    4             7,04
```

Second table y with limit seler id:

```
seler_id
   1
   2
   4
   5
```

I try to join table y to table x to get score like this

```
id_seler      hour            sum expensex
   1        1:00              3,04
   1        2:00              null
   1        3:00              null
   1        4:00              null
   2        1:00              null
   2        2:00              4,04
   2        3:00              null
   2        4:00              null
   4        1:00              null
   4        2:00              null
   4       3:00               7,04
   4        4:00              6,04 
   5        1:00              null
   5        2:00              null
   5       3:00               null
   5       4:00               null
```

I want that query back me all id_seler for all hours with expenses.

I tried to use left join

```
from y left join x on x.id_seller=y.id_seller
group by hour
```

but it back me null only for this id_seler which is dosent exist in table x next of last hour - In this exaple for id_seler=5

Comment: Please share the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

you don't get results for times that aren't set in table x because you don't ask for them. SQL doesn't know what an hour is or how it works.

use a temp table for every time slot you always want to see like

```
CREATE TABLE #TIMES ([TIMES] nvarchar(5))
INSERT INTO #TIMES([TIMES]) VALUES(<insert the hours here>)
```

then join y on the times table (on 1 = 1) so you get every time slot for every SELER_ID. left join those on table x (on id_seler = id_seler and x.hour = times.times)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then a `left join` to bring in existing values:

```
select h.hour, y.id_seler, x.expenses
       row_number() over (
from (select distinct hour from x) h cross join
     y left join
     x
     on x.hour = h.hour and x.id_seler = y.id_seler;
```

Your column name suggests that you want aggregation, but aggregation does not seem necessary based on the data and the rest of the question.  However, you can add `group by h.hour, y.id_seler` if you need aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have all of the `Hour` values in your final result, you have to `CROSS JOIN` table `y` with a full list of `Hour` values.

The best solution would be to build a table with all of the `Hour` values that you need in it. If you can't build a table, you can use a sub-query, or you might be able to derive the `Hours` values from table `x`.

#### Sub-Query

```
SELECT 
  h.Hour,
  y.Seler_ID
FROM
  (
    SELECT v.Hour
    FROM (VALUES ('0:00'),
                 ('1:00'),
                 ('2:00'),
                 ('3:00')
                 -- Keep adding values here.
          ) v(Hour)
  ) AS h
  CROSS JOIN
  y;
```

#### From Table `x`

```
SELECT 
  h.Hour,
  y.Seler_ID
FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      Hour
    FROM x
  ) AS h
  CROSS JOIN
  y;
```

Either way, the results (short version):

```
  0:00   1  
  1:00   1  
  2:00   1  
  3:00   1  
  0:00   2  
  1:00   2  
  2:00   2  
  3:00   2  
  0:00   4  
  1:00   4  
  2:00   4  
  3:00   4  
  0:00   5  
  1:00   5  
  2:00   5  
  3:00   5
```

Now that you have all of the `Hour` and `seler_id` values, `LEFT JOIN` to your `x` table to get the `expenses`.

```
SELECT 
  h.Hour,
  y.Seler_ID,
  x.expenses
FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      Hour
    FROM x
  ) AS h
  CROSS JOIN
  y
  LEFT JOIN
  x
    ON x.Hour = h.Hour
    ANS x.seler_id = y.seler_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the `distinct hour` and `cross join` it with `Y` table, Then you will need to `left join` it with `X` table as follows:

```
SELECT
    Y.SELER_ID,
    XX.HOUR,
    X.EXPENSES
FROM
    Y CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT HOUR AS HOUR
          FROM X
    ) XX
    LEFT JOIN X ON X.HOUR = XX.HOUR AND X.ID_SELER = Y.SELER_ID
```